# Hide user name and password from build.properties in ANT

Tags: ant, migration

I have created **build.properties** and **build.xml** for the ANT setup to retrieve components.

**build.properties** looks like below:

```
# build.properties
#

# Specify the login credentials for the desired Salesforce organization
sf.username = <User name>
sf.password = <Password>
#sf.sessionId = <Insert your Salesforce session id here.  Use this or username/password above.  Cannot use both>
#sf.pkgName = <Insert comma separated package names to be retrieved>
#sf.zipFile = <Insert path of the zipfile to be retrieved>
#sf.metadataType = <Insert metadata type name for which listMetadata or bulkRetrieve operations are to be performed>

# Use 'https://login.salesforce.com' for production or developer edition (the default if not specified).
# Use 'https://test.salesforce.com for sandbox.
sf.serverurl = https://test.salesforce.com

sf.maxPoll = 200
# If your network requires an HTTP proxy, see http://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html for configuration.
#
```

**build.xml** looks like below:

```
<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" default="test" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">

    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>

    <!-- Setting default value for username, password and session id properties to empty string
         so unset values are treated as empty. Without this, ant expressions such as ${sf.username}
         will be treated literally.
    -->
    <condition property="sf.username" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.username"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.password" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.password"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.sessionId" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.sessionId"/> </not> </condition>

    <taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:com.salesforce">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="ant-salesforce.jar" />           
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <!-- Shows retrieving code; only succeeds if done after deployCode -->
    <target name="retrieveCode">
      <!-- Retrieve the contents listed in the file codepkg/package.xml into the codepkg directory -->
      <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="..\force-app\main\default" unpackaged="package.xml"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

In **build.properties** my user name and password in written in plain text.

We maintain **build.properties** in GitLab, I don't want everyone to see the credentials.

I tried creating Environment Variable like below:

[image]

And used them in **build.properties** like below:

```
# build.properties
#

# Specify the login credentials for the desired Salesforce organization
sf.username = %SF_USER%
sf.password = %SF_PASSWORD%
#sf.sessionId = <Insert your Salesforce session id here.  Use this or username/password above.  Cannot use both>
#sf.pkgName = <Insert comma separated package names to be retrieved>
#sf.zipFile = <Insert path of the zipfile to be retrieved>
#sf.metadataType = <Insert metadata type name for which listMetadata or bulkRetrieve operations are to be performed>

# Use 'https://login.salesforce.com' for production or developer edition (the default if not specified).
# Use 'https://test.salesforce.com for sandbox.
sf.serverurl = https://test.salesforce.com

sf.maxPoll = 200
# If your network requires an HTTP proxy, see http://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html for configuration.
#
```

But getting below error while retrieval:

[image]

How can I hide my password in **build.properties**, So it can't be seen by other people when committed to Git.

Comment: There is a misspelling in properties: %SF_USERE% => %SF_USER% . Also are you concatenating security token with password?

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Frodo. Using the correct ones doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

In your build.preperties I'm not sure to get the value from the environment variables, but you can do it in your build.xml.

You can do something like this:

```
<condition property="sf.username" value="${env.SF_USER}">
<condition property="sf.password" value="${env.SF_PASSWORD}">
```